# Cannot optimize images using EWW Optimizer (plugin) in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, optimization

Im trying to optimize images in wordpress using the EWW Optimizer plugin, but after clicking the button optimize, i got the following exception:

> Operation Interrupted

I think it can be caused by the size of the pictures, but not sure and don't know how can be fixed. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Lot of causes are possible. Most probably related to your hosting.

Did you tried increasing WP memory limit to 512MB? Here is how to do: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/increasing-the-wordpress-memory-limit/

Note that WP memory limit can be force by your host.

Cheers,
Francesco

Comment: Sad to hear that! I would suggest to contact your hosting provider or test another similar service like https://imagify.io/